# Youtube API how to play video from 0 seconds when video ends? Iframe, Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, html5-video, youtube-javascript-api

So I have My code it detects when the player has stopped the problem is I can't get it to play from 0 seconds when the end has come I'm using the Iframe embed that holds a html5 video, Here is the code!

```
<div id="youtube-fs"><iframe id="youtube-iframe" type="text/html" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/LYL0lzmrvk8?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&rel=0&wmode=transparent&vq=hd1080&hd=1&loop=1" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque" ></iframe> <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
      var player;
      function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('youtube-iframe', { events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange } }); }
      function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); }
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) { player.playVideoAt(0); } // Play from 0 seconds
      }
        -->
    </script>

    </div>
```

Any idea's? maybe seekTo? or something
Thank you in advance!

Used `player.seekTo(1, true);` that worked

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) { 
          player.seekTo(0); 
          player.playVideo();

        } // Play from 0 seconds
      }
```

http://plnkr.co/aoSupfT7vXGGoM99sNwl